# Dart Image to File in local storage

Tags: dart, dart-io

I'm using the `Image` class from the package [image](https://pub.dev/packages/image). I have to download a image from internet and save it in my local storage. Then modify this image and save the changes. I have done the first 2 steps, but when i'm saving the file, this is corrupted and the Image Viewer dont recognizit as a image file. This is the code where the image is saved after the changes.

```dart
  var response = await client.get(urlToImage);
  var img = await File('./network_image.jpg').writeAsBytes(response.bodyBytes);
  Image image = decodeImage(img.readAsBytesSync())

  var f = await File('./image.jpg').writeAsBytes(image.getBytes()); // this doesnt work
  // var f = await File('./image.jpg').writeAsBytes(image.data); // this doesnt work
```

The `File.writeAsBytes` expects a `List<int> bytes`, and the `Image.data` and `Image.getBytes()` returns `Uint32List`and `Uint8List` respectively.

I'm not using Flutter, only dart for a command line program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image object stores the image data in an unencoded format. Remember you decoded it with `decodeImage`. It stores the raw colors of the image. You need to re encode the image data or your image viewer needs to handle whatever image format of data `getBytes` returns.

The easier solution is probably to re encode. You seem to want a [`JpegEncoder`](https://pub.dev/documentation/image/latest/image/JpegEncoder-class.html).

```dart
var f = await File('./image.jpg').writeAsBytes(JpegEncoder().encodeImage(image));
```